# Flash is not working under TOR and vk.com

Tags: flash

After upgrade to newest version of tor (5.0.7) and flash (20.0.0.267) flash player is not working on specific site (vk.com) on another sites it's works well.

On vk.com flash is not even launching, no any indicator as usual.

Could you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

Press F12 and take a look for errors. And keep in mind that VK.com is working properly in full scale ONLY if you're using Tor as a router for a whole machine. Confirmed it with Android and PC versions